# Setting up second router

Tags: wireless-networking, bridge-router

Background: I recently moved in with my girlfriend and the only option she has for broadband is ATT DSL and the router she must use is not the best.

It is a Netgear model B90-755025-15

The wifi drops periodically, the internet drops periodically, needs to be reset frequently, etc.

We can't really do much about the frequent internet drops as there are no other broadband providers in her area and AT&T doesn't want to fix it.

However, I do want to fix the internal network stability as we frequently stream music and movies from our NAS to our XBMCs.

I have an ASUS rt-66r that I would like to setup to handle the internal wifi and DCHP and just use the AT&T Netgear B90-755025-15 only when we go out to the internet.

Currently both routers are connected by ethernet in the lan port (not the uplink port)

Both routers are on the same subnet (192.168.1.*) have the same subnet mask (255.255.255.0) etc.

When I connect with wireless to either router I cannot ping the other router

I really appreciate any help here. What can I

Comment: Routes route traffic between different (sub)networks. Try LAN -> Asus LAN (network 1) -> Asus WAN -> Netgear LAN (network 2) -> Netgear WAN -> Internet (network 3)

Comment: You don't want a second router, you want an access point. Wifi != router.

Comment: Thanks, Techie007 but I'm really trying to avoid double double nat if at all possible

Comment: wurtel, I do want a second router.  An access point would be easier but it would still have the ATT Netgear controlling the network and when it dropped the internal network an access point wouldn't be much help at all.

I have a great router and want it to control all internal networking on only use the ATT router when accessing the internet